# Zeno's unusual pets

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

Zeno's pets walked forever, yet never seemed to arrive where they were going. What were they?

**Hint**

> The Zeno in question is the ancient Greek philosopher, Zeno of Elea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an answer similar to @Deusovi’s, but potentially maybe phonetically closer?

> Zeno’s Pair of *Ducks*?

The pun is bad, and I feel bad…. Haha.

Comment: Gung'f vg, lrf--jung V unq va zvaq (gubhtu Qrhfbav'f nafjre vf evtug gbb). V qba'g srry onq ng *nyy* nobhg gur cha... :)

Answer (score 13):

Are you looking for

> "Zeno's pair of dogs" (a pun on [Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes))?

Comment: Gung'f abg gur bar V unq va zvaq, ohg n pbeerpg nafjre naq qrsvavgryl n tbbq bar! V'yy tvir vg n ovg gb frr vs nal bgure pbeerpg nafjref pbzr va orsber pubbfvat na nafjre.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps they were

> A [krill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krill), [leas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lea_(insect)) and the tortoise (which is a pun on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise))

Comment: Alright, this is also funny - well done

Comment: Your pun-fu is strong... :)

Answer (score 1):

A tenuous connection at best, but could they be Zeno's

> fleas? As in, they can go round and round his head, without ever arriving anywhere. The hint could then refer to Zeno of **F**lea.

Comment: Not quite, but clever